# C++ Naming Conventions

Tags: c++, naming-conventions, capitalization

I was wondering about the naming conventions in C++, specifically where and what gets capitalized. I guess what I'm asking is (having come from languages like Java and C#) why are things like std::vector and std::string are not capitalized?

As a follow up, if I was typedefing a std::string to be something else (in my case a "world"), should I call it ...

```
 typedef std::string world;
```

or

```
 typedef std::string World;
```

I've looked around at previous posts and style guides (several listed below), but none seemed to address this directly (links below). The Google guide said:
"The names of all types — classes, structs, typedefs, and enums — have the same naming convention. Type names should start with a capital letter and have a capital letter for each new word. No underscores." So that makes it seem like it should be the latter -- but this seems odd since the std library doesn't even slightly follow this convention. Is it just one of those things where a bunch of people wrote the std library before styles were standardized and now (for compatibility reason) it is too late to change/update it?

Thanks!

Previous Research:

- [C++ Naming Convention](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4883027/c-naming-convention)
- http://geosoft.no/development/cppstyle.html
- http://google-styleguide.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/cppguide.html

Comment: There isn't a single common naming convention, but a multitude, just as with C++ there isn't a single common library that provides functionality like the Java and C# standard libraries, but rather a multitude, an extreme diversity. Check out the Boost library, it's has a description of its conventions and rationales. The standard library is another source of convention, but one problem is that having names that look like standard library names isn't necessarily an advantage.

Comment: Oh, and *forget* the Google style guide. It was designed for an environment of lots of C style legacy code. Disconnected from that purpose much of its advice is ungood.

Comment: FWIW, that should be `typedef std::string world;`

Comment: my naming nounConvention CHANGES Daily.

Comment: You will get as many answers as there are programmers. I think types that are fundamental, pervasive and application agnostic like `std::string`  being all lower case gives them a feel like they are built in. So a `std::string` or a `std::set` feel part of the language like an `int` or a `double`. I only use capitalization for objects that contain more Application specific business logic. Like `CustomerManager`. I avoid capitalization in member functions wich seems common on Linux type systems.

Comment: Thanks guys! (I also updated my post so I put the typedef in the right order... whoops).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no standardised style. Just be consistent.

However, it is common to start user-defined types with a capital letter precisely so they *can't* be confused with built-in types or types in the standard library.

Anyway, it should be:

```
typedef std::string World;
```

Or in C++11 you can write:

```
using World = std::string;
```

Comment: So Pascal case?

Comment: or just type out all the `std::` when it really matters.

Answer (score 1):

I feel like this link to a similar question would help you:

[What is the preferred naming conventions du jour for c++?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/361176/what-is-the-preferred-naming-conventions-du-jour-for-c?rq=1)

And as most everyone else has mentioned, it's important to do two things:

1. pick a style
2. stick with it